# I am trying to count occurrences of a string in table by date

Tags: r

Sorry if that question is to obvious but I couldn't find solution. I have table

```
      Date string
2013-03-12 str1
2013-03-12 str2
2013-03-12 str3
2013-03-12 str3
2013-03-12 str2
2013-03-13 str1
2013-03-13 str2
2013-03-13 str2
```

And I want to count how many times each string occurs every day.

So answer should look like:

```
2013-03-12 str1 1
2013-03-12 str2 2
2013-03-12 str3 2
2013-03-13 str1 1
2013-03-13 str2 2
2013-03-13 str3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Without reproducible data it is hard to solve this but roughly:

```
Date <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
String <- LETTERS[c(1,2,1,1,2)]
table(Date,String)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, here are two methods to solve this.

1) Using `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Date, string, .drop = FALSE)

#  Date       string     n
#  <fct>      <fct>  <int>
#1 2013-03-12 str1       1
#2 2013-03-12 str2       2
#3 2013-03-12 str3       2
#4 2013-03-13 str1       1
#5 2013-03-13 str2       2
#6 2013-03-13 str3       0
```

2) `group_by` + `summarise`

```
df %>%
  group_by(Date, string, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  #If there are only these two columns in the data we can also use group_by_all
  #group_by_all(.drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

This is assuming your `string` column is already a `factor`, if it is not convert it to `factor` first before applying the above.

```
df$string <- factor(df$string)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("2013-03-12", "2013-03-13"), class = "factor"), 
string = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("str1", "str2", "str3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: simply using `table` and `data.frame`, i.e., `z <- data.frame(table(df))`, then:

```
> z[order(z$Date),]
        Date string Freq
1 2013-03-12   str1    1
3 2013-03-12   str2    2
5 2013-03-12   str3    2
2 2013-03-13   str1    1
4 2013-03-13   str2    2
6 2013-03-13   str3    0
```

**Solution 2**: `ave()` can almost make it, except for the `str` with `2013-03-13`

```
df$cnt <- with(df,ave(seq(nrow(df)), Date, string, FUN = length))
> unique(df)
        Date string cnt
1 2013-03-12   str1   1
2 2013-03-12   str2   2
3 2013-03-12   str3   2
6 2013-03-13   str1   1
7 2013-03-13   str2   2
```